# Rails 4.2 + ActiveModel Serializer 0.8.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have these files and I can get that ActiveModel Serializer works.

```ruby
# 
# congif/routes.rb
namespace :dealer do
  resources :users do
    resources :orders do
      get 'search_dealer_profile', on: :collection
```

```ruby
# 
# app/serializers/profile_serializer.rb
class  ProfileSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
end
```

```ruby
# 
# app/controllers/dealer/orders_controller.rb
class Dealer::OrdersController < Dealer::BaseController
  def search_dealer_profile
    profile = Profile.where(id: params[:id]).first

    # I tried
    # 
    # => Return a Json without use AMS. Object {id: 4, user_id: 4, name: "Alex", surname: "Sensation"…}
    render json: profile 

    # => Works in console but here I get this : uninitialized constant Dealer::OrdersController::ProfileSerializer
    render json: ProfileSerializer.new(profile).as_json 
  end
```

the `json` that I want is

```json
{:profile=>{:id=>4}}
```

I'm using

- Rails 4.2.0
- active_model_serializer 0.8.3

Anyone can help me?

Comment: and what format do you get it now?

Comment: If i use **render json: profile** it returns a full profile json object: {id: 4, user_id: 4, name: "Alex" ... + all attributes of profile

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the ProfileSerializer class is not being loaded. Ensure that `app/serializers` is included in config autoload paths.

**application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'serializers')
```